# Как добавить префикс к url в Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

У меня есть приложение на `Angular 2`. Все `url` на статику в этом приложении начинаются с `/` (что очевидно). Например, мой компанент находится по `url` `/app/register/register.component.js/` и найти я его могу, например по `http://localhost:3000/app/register/register.component.js`.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы `url` начинался с некоторого слова, например, `front`, а дальше идет путь к файлу. Путь выше должен выглядеть так: `http://localhost:3000/front/app/register/register.component.js`. При этом расположение папок в проекте должно быть прежним.

Comment: А имеет смысл делать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй добавить в index.html

```
<head><base href="/front/"></head>
```

Comment: Сделал. При попытке зайти на `http://localhost:3000/front/` поиск происходит в папке `front`, которой у меня нет.

Comment: А что обслуживает статику на сервере? (nginx, dev-server(webpack) или что-то еще?)

Comment: Если все таки не хотите менять каталоги, то придется прописать как серверу отдавать данные по URI /front/**. Например для nginx`a прописать нужный location

Comment: Использую `nginx` c таким конфигом: `server {
  listen 80;
  access_log /var/log/nginx.access_log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx.error_log;

  location / {
    root /app/;
  }
}`

Comment: Вы предлагаете заменить `/` на `/front/` ? А как я тогда смогу еще поправить настройки `npm`, чтобы при дебаге и отладке через `npm start` все работало ?

Comment: Настройка в целом верная, только нужно прописать `location /front` вместо просто `location /`. Nginx уберет префикс при редиректе.

Comment: Для настройки webpack-dev-server взгляни на [документацию](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html). `--content-base <file/directory/url/port>: base path for the content.` вот это что-то похожее

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59906/discussion-between-faoxis-and-ruslan-masgutov).

Comment: Кстати, для успешной работы необходимо было еще поменять `root` на `alias`.